# Can't apply css to an iframe (the tag itself)

Tags: css, iframe, angular5

I have a content editor, and using that editor I want the user to be able to save links to external domains and display that as an iframe.

The iframe shows up, however when I try to apply CSS rules to the iframe (not the content inside the iframe, the tag itself), it doesn't work no matter what I do, and the rules doesn't even show up in developer console. I have more rules in the same sheet which work just fine.

Currently I have the following css:

```
iframe, .ql-video {
  height: 500px !important;
  width: 300px !important;
}
```

And this is the iframe I'm testing on:

```
<iframe class="ql-video" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="true" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/GKqEoSiAi90?showinfo=0" data-ss1531946992="1" data-ss1531947568="1"></iframe>
```

But the css simply doesn't affect it at all. It's not disabled or overriden, it simply doesn't show up at all.

[image: developer console rules]

If I add the rules to element.style it works as I want, however I need the rules to be there when the iframe is loaded. Unfortunatly I can't style it inline as the iframe (and the rest of the content) is retrieved from a database as a string.

This is how I retrieve the content (of which the iframe is a part of):

```
this.contentService.getSpecificArticle(this.route.snapshot.queryParams["newsid"]).subscribe( news => {
  document.getElementById('main_content').innerHTML = (news as any).content;
  ...
});
```

I'm doing it this way because the editor saves the content as pure html.

So any idea why I can't style the iframe tag this way?

**EDIT**: I've also tried interpolating the content however, angular sanitizes away the iframe then, as well as property binding, but then the content shows up as a string. This is why I used .innerHTML, but I do suspect it might be because of this, though I'm not sure why if that's the case, or how I can work around it.

Comment: is on a live site right now that we can look at?

Comment: Unfortunatly it's on localhost, sorry.

Comment: I'm not sure that it will make a difference but sometimes things get really finicky. Try removing "iframe," and leave just .ql-video { and the rest of your CSS.

Comment: I've tried using both by themselves, but neither show up or work.

Comment: doesn't answer what's not working correctly, you could try forcing it with .addClass() in a javascript line. Sorry it's tough without seeing much of the actual code to see what's going on.

Comment: Didn't work, still the same problem. :/

Comment: is it possible to get a codepen or jsfiddle set up with what you are trying to do so we can see a bit more of what you're working with?

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wxzrKV 

I uploaded the code, however it's not going to run by itself, it requires quite a few things, sorry.

The iframe string: <p>test test test2</p><iframe class="ql-video" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="true" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/GKqEoSiAi90?showinfo=0" data-ss1531946992="1"></iframe><p>test</p>

Comment: sorry, I'm at a bit of a loss myself, hopefully someone else can give a bit more insight.

Comment: Are you sure your css file is being loaded in the page? Like if you add `* { color: red !important }` does that affect anything?  Make sure there is no invalid CSS above your CSS (that could cause the CSS below it not to work)

Comment: Also, are you using CSS modules? Is the iframe inside another angular component? You might need `.ql-video::ng-deep { }` for it to apply to the component.

Comment: Yes the same sheet is used to style other content on the page. 2 comments above I posted a codepen of the code.

Comment: Okay it seems the CSS doesn't affect anything I append with the .innerHTML, not only the iframe (Added p {
  font-size: 100px !important;
  color: red !important;
}), the results is this: https://i.imgur.com/dKAOBIf.png

The "testest" texts are all <p>

Comment: does `/deep/ p { font-size: 100px !important; color: red !important; }` work?

Comment: Also can you try `document.getElementById('main_content').appendChild((news as any).content);` ? Just throwing out ideas

Comment: @ratherblue holy shit dude that works, post that as an answer please. /deep/ was all I needed.

Comment: alright, give me a sec

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your CSS is coming from a CSS module it won't apply styles to nested components. (Which is an important feature of CSS modules).

Try adding `/deep/` in front of your CSS for your iframe (although `/deep/` is deprecated, you're supposed to use `::ng-deep` instead now)

```
/deep/ .ql-video {
  height: 500px !important;
  width: 300px !important;
}
```

(Also, you're not reeaallly supposed to use `/deep/`, you should make CSS for that specific component and apply it there.)

Here's some information on Angular's component styles and 'deep': https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep

Comment: Thanks for the solution, as well as the additional information. Cheers.